# Currently having problems with deleting/overwriting from a file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm currently having problems trying to delete a line from a file and replace that line with different text (overwrite the line)

The code initially starts by extracting file contents to find the 
`DepartmentDetails` which can be used to find `DepartmentBudget` and subtract `AmountDue` and then create a new `DepartmentDetails` with the new budget
Once this is complete the code will add the N̳e̳w̳  `DepartmentDetails` which will leave the code with having the O͟l͟d͟ and the N̳e̳w̳ `DepartmentDetails` in the same folder.

The code should then delete the O͟l͟d͟ `DepartmentDetails` from the file making the N̳e̳w̳ `DepartmentBudget` take it's place. i.e. Overwrite the O͟l͟d͟ `DepartmentDetails` with the new one.

The problem is that the code does not delete the O͟l͟d͟ `DepartmentBudget` but adds a line space in between the O͟l͟d͟ and N̳e̳w̳ instead.

```
Private Sub BtnBillDept_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBillDept.Click
    Dim DepartmentStore As New Department
    Dim Order() As String = File.ReadAllLines(Dir$("OrderDetails.Txt"))
    Dim OrderID As String = TxtOrderID.Text
    Dim AmountDue As String = TxtAmountDue.Text
    Dim DeptID As String = (Trim(Mid(Order(OrderID), 5, 4)))
    Dim DepartmentDetails() As String = File.ReadAllLines(Dir$("DepartmentDetails.Txt"))

    Dim DepartmentBudget As String = (Trim(Mid(DepartmentDetails(DeptID), 35, 6)))

    Dim FormattedBudget As String = FormatCurrency(DepartmentBudget, 2)
    Dim YesNo As String
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter("DepartmentDetails.txt", True)

    DepartmentBudget = FormattedBudget - AmountDue
    DepartmentStore.DepartmentID = LSet(DeptID, 4)
    DepartmentStore.DepartmentHead = LSet((Trim(Mid(DepartmentDetails(DeptID), 5, 20))), 20)
    DepartmentStore.DepartmentName = LSet((Trim(Mid(DepartmentDetails(DeptID), 25, 10))), 10)
    DepartmentStore.DepartmentBudget = LSet(DepartmentBudget, 9)
    DeptID = UBound(DepartmentDetails)

    DepartmentDetails(DeptID) = ""
    File.WriteAllLines("DepartmentDetails", DepartmentDetails)
    sw.WriteLine(DepartmentStore.DepartmentID & DepartmentStore.DepartmentHead & DepartmentStore.DepartmentName & DepartmentStore.DepartmentBudget)
    sw.Close()`

    '***********************Having Problems Here***********************
    DepartmentDetails = File.ReadAllLines(Dir$("DepartmentDetails.Txt"))
    DepartmentDetails(DeptID) = ""
    File.WriteAllLines("DepartmentDetails", DepartmentDetails)
    '************************Having Problems Here**************************



    YesNo = MsgBox("Department has been billed. Would you like to delete the bill?", vbYesNo)
    If YesNo = vbYes Then

    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Why did you tag that with the [tag:c++] tag? I can't see any relation.

Comment: Turn `Option Strict On` now, you should be using it. Either add it at the top of your class and or set it at the project level (best option). Then once you get the "new" issues fixed and are still having problems, please update your post.

Comment: Don't assume the file is where you think it is.  Always give it the proper path.  Use the Path class to do that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ when I go to the about it says in product details: Microsoft Visual C++ 2017.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ I have turned on Option Strict but i'm afraid I don't know what you mean by the top of class and project level EDIT: I have searched it and changed these boxes to turn Strict on https://imgur.com/a/1qDHAQx. This has broke a lot of my code i'm not sure if this helped?

Comment: @Mr_monkog the purpose of `Option Strict On` is to show you the broken code so that you can resolve those issues. From your screenshot, it looks like you're trying to use string variables to do mathematical equations. And then implement @LarsTech suggestion to use the Path class. It should resolve your issues.

Comment: @JacobH Yes, this is so that I could easily save the variables into files. I have tried using the correct variables in the past but it doesn't use the LSet command correctly when I have tried this. I didn't realise using paths would fix these errors I will try and add this now

Comment: Sorry about the messy edits. I am not sure how to add it as a code example

Comment: Why would you need to LSet an integer though? That seems like a separate issue of trimming data. To add code you need to either a) quadruple space or b) surround your code in backticks (not apostrophes) like so \`test\` = `test`

Comment: @JacobH I am not sure. Unfortunately the school I go to made their only computer science specialist teacher redundant before I started this subject which has left us with 2 ICT teachers who have little coding knowledge. It's just been me and my friend who have been trying to work this assignment out.

Comment: I'm afraid to say that I am unsure how to add Path classes I will also look on the internet to find out how to do it but i feel it may be quicker to ask on here. Also my code is transferred from home to class regularly so would this cause problems if the path changes?

Comment: I think you would want to set the path as an input and then use the variable later in your code. But that is not your "problem" here, just a good coding suggestion. I'm pretty sure your underlying issue is *not* using one of the numeric data types for your math equations. Strings are not good for math. Try debugging line by line, and look at the variable value for DepartmentBudget. The suggestion to use `Option Strict On` should force you to use the correct data type.

Comment: "when I go to the about it says in product details: Microsoft Visual C++ 2017" When you go to the about box You will see 2 boxes. Installed Products gives the version of the individuals products in Visual Studio. The lower box, Product Details, give the details of the item that is selected in the first box. Visual C++ is an entirely different language.

Comment: @JacobH Thank you, I understand the data type errors that I have made and have corrected them. I still haven't checked whether I can now successfully overwrite a file but the corrections took a very long time to find out how to do and the internet was pretty limited. I will check that tomorrow before uploading the improved code and solution if successful.

Comment: @Mr_monkog Ok great! If you make very large code changes, your issue may be something different than your question here. If your issue does change, I would recommend making a new post.

Comment: Yes i will be making a new post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who decided that this text file would be formatted with fixed length fields? All this trimming and padding could be avoided with a simple comma delimited file or an xml file or a database where it really belongs.
Code is not tested. Comments and explanations in-line.

```
'I assume you have a class that looks something like this
'This uses automatic properties to save you having to
'type a getter, setter and backer field (the compiler adds these)
Public Class Department
    Public Property DepartmentID As Integer
    Public Property DepartmentHead As String
    Public Property DepartmentName As String
    Public Property DepartmentBudget As Decimal
End Class


Private Sub BtnBillDept_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnBillDept.Click
    Dim DepartmentStore As New Department
    'Drag an OpenFileDialog from the ToolBox to your form
    'It will appear in the lower portion of the design window
    Dim MyFilePath As String = ""
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select OrderDetails.Txt"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        MyFilePath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If
    Dim Order() As String = File.ReadAllLines(MyFilePath)
    'Changed data type, you use OrderID as an index for the Order array so it must be an Integer
    Dim OrderID As Integer
    'TryParse will check if you have a valid interger and fill OrderID variable
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TxtOrderID.Text, OrderID) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Order ID.")
        Return
    End If
    'EDIT per comment by Codexer 
    If OrderID > Order.Length - 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Order Number is too high")
        Return
    End If

    Dim AmountDue As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(TxtAmountDue.Text, AmountDue) Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid Amount Due")
        Return
    End If
    'I hope you realize that the first index in Order is zero
    'Mid is an old VB6 method around for compatibility
    'Use the .net Substring (startIndex As Integer, length As Integer)
    'The indexes in the string start with zero
    Dim DeptID As Integer = CInt(Order(OrderID).Substring(5, 4).Trim) '(Trim(Mid(Order(OrderID), 5, 4)))
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Select DepartmentDetails.txt"
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        MyFilePath = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    End If
    Dim DepartmentDetails() As String = File.ReadAllLines(MyFilePath)
    Dim DepartmentBudget As Decimal = CDec(DepartmentDetails(DeptID).Substring(35, 6).Trim) '(Trim(Mid(DepartmentDetails(DeptID), 35, 6)))
    'You don't need to format anything until you want to display it
    'Dim FormattedBudget As String = FormatCurrency(DepartmentBudget, 2)
    'A MessageBox returns a DialogResult
    Dim YesNo As DialogResult
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter(MyFilePath, True)
    'Shorcut way to write DepartmentBudget - AmountDue
    DepartmentBudget -= AmountDue
    'Set the property in the class with the proper data type
    DepartmentStore.DepartmentID = DeptID
    'Then prepare a string for the writing to the fil
    Dim PaddedID = CStr(DeptID).PadLeft(4)
    'The .net replacement for LSet is .PadLeft
    DepartmentStore.DepartmentHead = DepartmentDetails(DeptID).Substring(5, 20).Trim.PadLeft(20)
    DepartmentStore.DepartmentName = DepartmentDetails(DeptID).Substring(25, 10).Trim.PadLeft(20)
    'Set the property in the class with the proper data type
    DepartmentStore.DepartmentBudget = DepartmentBudget
    'Then prepare a string for the writing to the fil
    Dim PaddedBudget = CStr(DepartmentBudget).PadLeft(9)
    sw.WriteLine(PaddedID & DepartmentStore.DepartmentHead & DepartmentStore.DepartmentName & PaddedBudget)
    sw.Close()
    '***********************Having Problems Here***********************
    'This is using the path from the most recent dialog
    DepartmentDetails = File.ReadAllLines(MyFilePath)
    'Here you are changing the value of one of the elements in the DepartmentDetails array
    DepartmentDetails(DeptID) = ""
    'Public Shared Sub WriteAllLines (path As String, contents As String())
    'The string "DepartmentDetails" is not a path
    File.WriteAllLines(MyFilePath, DepartmentDetails)
    '************************Having Problems Here**************************
    YesNo = MessageBox.Show("Department has been billed. Would you like to delete the bill?", "Delete Bill?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo)
    If YesNo = DialogResult.Yes Then

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't know why you got downvoted, because this seems like a reasonable answer with code and supporting text.

Comment: One issue I can see is `Order(OrderID)`, the reason is clear. If the index doesn't exist then there is a problem; I would check first before accessing anything else IMHO and that goes with everything else that is an array in your post...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ OrderID is an Integer so it will be 0 if it isn't changed. Not an invalid index. Also there is a TryParse for OrderID.

Comment: @Mary it will be if a user enters 32 and theres only 9... in the array, then youll get an exception; this is what I am talking about...